# Splitting an input from terminal into a list of 2 items

Tags: python, list

Good day,
I am writing a program that allows user to write or view a note file, the program asks the user for input, and the user can either respond with "view " or "write ". My aim is to split the input to a list with 2 items, something like x = ['view', 'text file.txt']
My code example:

```
x = (input ()).lower()
x = x .strip().split (' ')
operation = x [0]
file = x [1]
```

But when the user input something like "write     mylife.txt", i get x as ['write', ' ',' ', ' ', 'mylife.txt'] and assignment doesn't make sense, What can I do about the spaces in between? Thanks

Comment: `operation, file = input().split()` should do. Also, if you are getting the input from the `cmd` you might want to take a look at the `sys` module and its `argv` function

Comment: `print("write mylife.txt".split(" "))` gives `['write', 'mylife.txt']`

Answer (score 1):

You could say simply:

```
x = x.strip().split()
```

because `.split()` without an input argument is a shortcut for splitting by one or more whitespace characters. Without that shortcut, or for any more-complex rule, you would need to learn to use *regular expressions* and call `re.split()` from the standard `re` module.

You could also say

```
operation, filename = x.strip().split(None, 1)
```

where the `None` gives you the one-or-more-whitespace default behaviour as above, and the `1` specifies that there should be at most one split (handy if the filename might contain whitespace).

You might also want to investigate `shlex.split()` from the standard `shlex` module because that would allow your users to enter long space-containing filenames in quotes (good for *multiple* filenames that may each contain spaces).